# How to get certain value based on text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, iif-function

A product with multiple pricing based on its e-commerce platform. How to I get the correct pricing based on the name of the ecommerce platform? Lets say Product A is $5 on Amazon and $7 on eBay. If there is a sale of Product A on eBay, it will display eBay price and if its a sale on Amazon, it will display amazon price.

I tried using IF and VLOOKUP function but ended up confusing the shit out of myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=@FILTER($C$2:$C$3,($A$2:$A$3=F2)*($B$2:$B$3=G2))
```

Or `MAP()` function for dynamic spill results.

```
=MAP(F2:F3,G2:G3,LAMBDA(x,y,TAKE(FILTER(C2:C3,(A2:A3=x)*(B2:B3=y)),1)))
```

[image]